# JSON schema with required properties nested inside an optional property

Tags: jsonschema

I need some help building a json schema for a react application which will be comply with the following dummy interface

```
 interface User {
    userName: string,
    systemAlerts: {
        alert1?: string | null,
        alert2?: string | null 
    },
    loginAlerts: {
        alert1?: {
            code1: string | null,
            code2: string | null
        },
        alert2?: {
            code1: string | null,
            code2: string | null
        },  
    }
}
```

So far I managed to come up with this schema

```
    {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "userName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "systemAlerts": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "alert1": {
                    "type": ["string", "null"]
                },
                "alert2": {
                    "type": ["string", "null"]
                }
            },
            "required": []
        },
        "loginAlerts": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "alert1": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "code1": {
                            "type": ["string", "null"]
                        },
                        "code2": {
                            "type": ["string", "null"]
                        },
                    },
                    "required": ["code1","code2"]
                },
                "alert2": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "code1": {
                            "type": ["string", "null"]
                        },
                        "code2": {
                            "type": ["string", "null"]
                        },
                    },
                    "required": ["code1","code2"]
                },
            },
            "required": []
        },

    },
    "required": ["userName", "systemAlerts", "loginAlerts"],
};
```

I'm really struggling to get all these optional properties working as per interface.

This is a valid example.

```
const obj = {
        "userName": "User",
        "systemAlerts": {
            "alert1": null,
            "alert2": "999"
        },
        "loginAlerts": {
            "alert1": {
                "code1": "22",
                "code2": null
            },
            "alert2": {
                "code1": "33",
                "code2": "44"
            }
        }
    };
```

However, this example also passes validation despite containing incorrect properties like `alert11` instead of `alert1` etc.

```
const obj = {
        "userName": "User",
        "systemAlerts": {
            "alert11": null,
            "alert22": "999"
        },
        "loginAlerts": {
            "alert5": {
                "code11": "22",
                "code22": null
            },
            "alert7": {
                "code11": "33",
                "code22": "44"
            }
        }
    };
```

This example fails validation which is correct because `code1` and `code2` are missing

```
const obj = {
        "userName": "User",
        "systemAlerts": {
            "alert11": null,
            "alert22": "999"
        },
        "loginAlerts": {
            "alert1": {
                "code11": null,
                "code22": null
            },
            "alert2": {
                "code33": null,
                "code44": null
            }
        }
    };
```

So basically, the rules are:

- `systemAlerts` is required and can be an empty object or contain only `alert1` or `alert2` or both. Any other properties should make it invalid
- `loginAlerts` is required and can be an empty object or contain only `alert1` or `alert2` or both properties. If either `alert1` or `alert2` or both are present, they should always have `code1` and `code2` properties.

I've tried `oneOf`, `allOf`, dependencies etc but it keeps failing validation so I'm really stuck at the moment.

If someone could help me that would be awesome.

Comment: Can you provide some more detail as to what's not working for you?  Can you give an example of data that should validate but isn't or data that shouldn't validate but is?

Comment: @gregsdennis Sorry, i have now updated my questions with few examples and some rules to clarify what is exactly required. Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, with your schema. The only thing you are missing is the [`additionalProperties`](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#additional-properties) setting, which when set to `"addtionalProperties": false` will prohibit any other properties than defined in the object.

Based on the rules in the end of your post, that schema should be pretty straight forward:

1. You need an object with three properties `"userName", "systemAlerts", "loginAlerts"`, all of them also added to `"required": ["userName", "systemAlerts", "loginAlerts"]`. furthermore you need to set `"additionalProperties": false`, this prohibits other properties than `userName`, `systemAlerts` and `loginAlerts`
2. The `systemAlerts` object has two properties `alert1` and `alert2` of type `["string", "null"]` and again `"additionalProperties": false`. As both alerts are optional, either do `"required": []` or omit it entirely
3. The `loginAlerts`object has two properties `alert1` and `alert2` of type `object` and again `"additionalProperties": false`. As both alerts are optional, either do `"required": []` or omit it entirely
4. Each of the alerts in `loginAlerts` has properties `code1` and `code2` of type `["string", "null"]` and again `"additionalProperties": false`. As both codes are required, add them also to `"required": ["code1", "code2"]`

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "userName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "loginAlerts": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "alert1": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "code1": {
              "type": ["string", "null"],
              "enum": ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
            },
            "code2": {
              "type": ["string", "null"]
            }
          },
          "required": [],
          "additionalProperties": false,
        },
        "alert2": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "code1": {
              "type": ["string", "null"]
            },
            "code2": {
              "type": ["string", "null"]
            }
          },
          "required": ["code1", "code2"],
          "additionalProperties": false
        }
      }
    },
    "systemAlerts": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "alert1": {
          "type": ["string", "null"]
        },
        "alert2": {
          "type": ["string", "null"]
        }
      },
      "required": [],
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  },

  "required": ["systemAlerts", "loginAlerts", "userName"],
  "additionalProperties": false

}
```

You could even simplify the schema by creating a custom type `loginAlert` in the `$defs` section of your schema and then referencing to that type in the properties

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "$defs": {
    "loginAlert": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "code1": {
          "type": ["string", "null"]
        },
        "code2": {
          "type": ["string", "null"]
        }
      },
      "required": ["code1", "code2"],
      "additionalProperties": false,
    }
  },
  "properties": {
    "loginAlerts": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "alert1": {
          "$ref": "#/$defs/loginAlert"
        },
        "alert2": {
          "$ref": "#/$defs/loginAlert"
        }
      }
    },
    ...
```

Comment: This is great! Exactly what I was looking for and seems to work great. Thanks! One requirement I completely omitted is that system alerts and login alerts cannot be empty objects at the same. At least one of them must contain properties. Is there an easy way to update your solution?

Comment: Hm, that last requirement is a bit more complicated. I'll have to think about that

Comment: Dont worry about it then. I will run a check first before validating against the schema. Your solution works great. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've just identified an issue. It appears that validation is successful even if alert1 is a number. Also, is it possible to limit what exactly the string could be. For example code1 couold only be "enabled" or "disabled" or null.  Any other string would make it invalid.

Comment: I don't know what validator you are using. But if it accepts a number for something that is defined as string or object, it's an issue with the validator and not with the schema ...  Or did you enclose your number with double quotes? like `"alert1": "3.5"`?

Comment: And for the second requirement of restricting the values of the strings to certain values, see the updated answer. Ie using `"enum": ["foo", "bar", "baz"]`

Comment: Hold on I think I know what I did wrong... Let me do more testing and I will let you know.

Comment: All good now. Very happy with this approach. Your help is much appreciated.